# Unable to create distribution

Tags: python-3.x

The problem is:

- trying to use cmd to for `setup.py sdist`
- cmd returns the message:

[image: Detailed CMD Message]

The expected result is that my module should have been transformed into a distribution and installed to my Python.

Below is the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'nester',
  version = '1.0.0',
  py_modules = ['nester'],
  author = 'hfpython',
  author_email = 'hfpython@headfirstlabs.com',
  url = 'http://www.headfirstlabs.com',
  description = 'A simple printer of nested lists',
)
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text. It's not searchable, or copy+pastable.

Comment: Please provide your `setup.py` file. Have you tried `cd`ing to the same directory as `setup.py`

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hi! noted! I will take note of it from now on.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Hi! thanks for the help! I have edited the post and include the content of setup.py

Comment: @JV17 please note Blorgbeard's request. You'll get a better response if you swap your image for text.